# Interpreting complex C++ Definition

Tags: c++, templates, signature

For a recent class project, we were required to modify code within an existing class method in a MIPS simulator.  I completed the assignment successfully but it has bothered me that I really didn't understand the method declaration:

```
template<class State, class Addr_t, bool Energy>
typename CacheAssoc<State, Addr_t, Energy>::Line
*CacheAssoc<State, Addr_t, Energy>::findLine2Replace(Addr_t addr, bool ignoreLocked)
{
    // ...
}
```

There's a lot going there.  Can you help break it down for me?

---

[Here is a link to the header](https://github.com/masc-ucsc/esesc/blob/master/misc/libsuc/CacheCore.h)

[Here is a link to the code file](https://github.com/masc-ucsc/esesc/blob/master/misc/libsuc/CacheCore.cpp)

Comment: I think you mean that you would like help to understand the method declaration, not the method definition. The definition is everything in between { }. Am I correct?

Comment: What don't you understand? It's a template for a member function `CacheAssoc<State, Addr_t, Energy>::findLine2Replace` with return type `typename CacheAssoc<State, Addr_t, Energy>::Line *`.

Comment: Joakim, you are correct in what I was really asking.  ty.

Answer (score 2):

This is the definition of the `findLine2Replace` method for the template class `CacheAssoc` (including everything within the braces which you have omitted).

```
template<class State, class Addr_t, bool Energy>
```

These are the template parameters, the first two are type template parameters and the final one is a boolean parameter (can only be true or false). This should be the same as it appears for the class definition.

```
typename CacheAssoc<State, Addr_t, Energy>::Line*
```

This is the function return type. The `typename` keyword is necessary as `CacheAssoc` is a dependent type (it relies on unspecified template parameters). `::Line` must be a type that is defined within the `CacheAssoc` class.

```
CacheAssoc<State, Addr_t, Energy>::findLine2Replace(Addr_t addr, bool ignoreLocked)
```

Is the function name and argument list. If you were to define this method within the scope of the `CacheAssoc` class, the following would not be necessary `CacheAssoc<State, Addr_t, Energy>::`.

Comment: Mansoor.  Your answer is exactly the information what I hoping looking for.  Thank you.